Running unit tests with Spark 3.3.0 on Java 17 fails with IllegalAccessError: cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer on Team city build
My build step sonar failing with below error
 java.lang.IllegalAccessError
12:19:36       java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x763d9750) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x763d9750
        at com.zsassociates.zdf.spark.transform.AsyncDataframeTransformerTest.setUpBeforeClass(AsyncDataframeTransformerTest.java:26)

i have below docker file in place
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk

# Update and upgrade the apk
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add git \
    wget \
    bash

# Download and install Maven
ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.8.5
RUN wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz && \
    rm apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz && \
    mv apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION /usr/lib/mvn

# Set environment variables for Maven
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/lib/mvn
ENV PATH $MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH

# Copy Maven settings.xml into the container
COPY settings.xml /usr/lib/mvn/conf/
COPY settings.xml /root/.m2/

# Set MAVEN_OPTS and JAVA_OPTS environment variables
ENV MAVEN_OPTS="--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED"
ENV JAVA_OPTS="--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED"

# Download and install Hadoop
ENV HADOOP_VERSION 3.3.4
RUN wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION.tar.gz && \
    rm hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION.tar.gz && \
    mv hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION /usr/local/hadoop

# Set environment variables for Hadoop
ENV HADOOP_HOME /usr/local/hadoop
ENV PATH $HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$PATH

# Set Hadoop environment variables in hadoop-env.sh
RUN echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto" >> $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh


i have already tried providing command line arg in my pom under surefire
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          </includes>
<!--          <argLine>&#45;&#45;add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>-->
        </configuration>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
</plugin>

Still it is not working if i provide --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED in pom it throws below error
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project zdf-connector-spark: There are test failures.
  
  Please refer to /app/buildagent/work/300a0c3d1b5175e5/zdf-connector-spark/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
  Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
  The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
  Command was /bin/sh -c cd /app/buildagent/work/300a0c3d1b5175e5/zdf-connector-spark && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-amazon-corretto/bin/java --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED -jar /app/buildagent/work/300a0c3d1b5175e5/zdf-connector-spark/target/surefire/surefirebooter597987665867464764.jar /app/buildagent/work/300a0c3d1b5175e5/zdf-connector-spark/target/surefire 2024-06-20T11-16-56_327-jvmRun1 surefire5114296731364299684tmp surefire_0504669054215296620tmp
  Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
  Process Exit Code: 1
  org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
  Command was /bin/sh -c cd /app/buildagent/work/300a0c3d1b5175e5/zdf-connector-spark && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-amazon-corretto/bin/java --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED -jar /app/buildagent/work/300a0c3d1b5175e5/zdf-connector-spark/target/surefire/surefirebooter597987665867464764.jar /app/buildagent/work/300a0c3d1b5175e5/zdf-connector-spark/target/surefire 2024-06-20T11-16-56_327-jvmRun1 surefire5114296731364299684tmp surefire_0504669054215296620tmp
  Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
  Process Exit Code: 1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:748)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1159)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:932)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

i have also tried providing command under JVM command line parameters on sonar build step
As part of this debug i have only enabled a single test case which runs on sparksession still it is failing.
Most of the issues related to cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer are not helping me.
I also created docker with java8-hadoop configuration but facing same issue.
Am i missing anything as i have explored almost all possible solutions available on stackoverflow.
